# Extract image url from html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 vcenter no-pad-top no-pad-bot">
<img itemprop="image" src="/uploads/images/cache/20955226c5c975c230cb8e1f8cff0e6f1583249561_150_150.png" alt="SPINNEY MOBILE DEVELOPMENT" class="b-lazy pull-left center-block img-responsive b-loaded"></div>
```

I need to extract image from this particular class only

```
"/uploads/images/cache/20955226c5c975c230cb8e1f8cff0e6f1583249561_150_150.png"
```

My code:

```
url = "https://www.appfutura.com/developers/spinney"
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
soup.prettify()

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(link.get('src'))
```

how can i Acheive further task?
please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly :

When printing img "src" attribute you can check whether it contains "/uploads/images/cache/" or not.

```
img = soup.find_all('img')

for link in img:
    if "/uploads/images/cache/" in link.get('src'):
         print(link.get('src'))
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a module called 'webbrowser' which lets you open a url, such as:

```
import webbrowser
url = "https://www.appfutura.com/developers/spinney"
webbrowser.open(url)
```

but to DOWNLOAD a url you must import requests

```
import requests


url = 'https://www.appfutura.com/developers/spinney'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

open('yoururlname.html', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

if you created a folder with that program, the download will end up in your folder. the program will be just a black screen popping up and closing, and the url will be downloaded